# Calculating an arc path in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I couldn't figure out how to simulate this. The Red arrow head is in a static position. The background, has a curved path. I'm just moving the background position to make it seems the arrow head is moving along that curved path.

[Red Arrow http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/6636/redarrowe.png](http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/6636/redarrowe.png)

What I have right now is the arrow moving along at a 45 degree angle to the destination. But what I'm trying to achieve is the arrow moving along that dashed path.

```
var interval = 100;

var currX = -82;    // Current x position
var currY = -342;   // Current y position

var destX = -750;   // Destination x position
var destY = -850;   // Destination y position

var currentDuration = 0;
var duration = 1800 * 1000;  // Duration

var $bg = $('#flight-wrapper');

var intbg = window.setInterval(function(){
    currentDuration += interval;

    var leftX = destX - currX;  // X pixels left
    var leftY = destY - currY;  // Y pixels left

    var leftDuration = duration - currentDuration;  // Duration left

    var tickX = leftX / leftDuration * interval;    // Pixel to offset
    var tickY = leftY / leftDuration * interval;    // Pixel to offset

    var newX = currX + tickX;
    var newY = currY + tickY;

    // Prevent it going further than the destination X & Y pixel
    currX = newX <= destX ? destX : newX;
    currY = newY <= destY ? destY : newY;

    if ( currX <= destX && currY <= destY ) {
        window.clearTimeout(intbg);
    }

    $bg.css({
        backgroundPosition: Math.floor(currX) + 'px ' + Math.floor(currY) + 'px'
    });
}, interval);
```

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Do you want the math explained or is it ok to post a working solution using a library?

Comment: Can I have the math explained please.

Comment: Given that your arc can be seen as a section of a circle, you can use `sin` and `cos` to transform x/y accordingly. But first of all you should use a jQuery plugin which allows you to animate `background-position` which makes your current code obsolete and a one-liner. Then specify your own easing functions using sine and cosine.

Answer (score 0):

Given the point `p = (x_t, y_t)` which is where the arrow is at any given time `t`, you need to find out what the [tangent to your curve at the point `p` numerically](http://www.intmath.com/differentiation/2-slope-tangent.php) which will tell you exactly how the arrow should point.